# Why are some of the top Holders of a token a contract? What is this use case?

Tags: blockchain, chain-analysis

I'm trying to understand why a specific token: https://etherscan.io/token/0x826180541412d574cf1336d22c0c0a287822678a#balances

Has many contracts that are holders of the token vs individual wallet addresses? Is there a reason for this? This is a token still in its launch phase. Is it so they can lock these tokens as a vesting period? I'm just trying to understand this from analyzing the transaction history.

[image]

Comment: Looking at the contract, there are several Safe wallet, a couple of vesting/staking contracts from the team, a proxy contract. I see nothing strange, but without analyzing the source code is difficult to assert if it is problematic or not. Probably, you should ask the team what's the initial token distribution.